# I define some vars and i use them to retrieve the lat&lng which works, but after i pass the variable to another function doesn`t work

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, int, var

The problem that I face is as follows.

I`m creating some variables in the function with the keyword var x =0; at some point i assign a new value to x and then i log it to the console and it shows the right value. but when i try to use the x(new value) to concatenate it with a string/link i get 0 instead the new value.

I tried to leave x without the 0 and after that is says undefined. Where i`m wrong here?

Tried:
var x;
var x=0;

in the first scenario it will be undefined and in the second one will be 0.

```
    geocode();
    function geocode() {

    var lng = 0;
    var lattitude = 0;
    var lattitudeb = 0;
    var lngb = 0;

    var locationA = '1234';
    var locationB = '1323';

    axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
        params: {
            address: locationA,
            key: 'AIzaSyBpHiHzK323fsregSMCDbgX33xAUB_Cwwi8'
        }
    }).then(function (response) {

        lattitude = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        lng = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;


       console.log(lattitude);
       console.log(lng);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        });

    axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
        params: {
            address: locationB,
            key: 'AIzaSyBpHiHzK3434fdf3434rferfeX33xAUB_Cwwi8'
        }
    }).then(function (response) {

        lattitudeb = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
        lngb = response.data.results[0].geometry.location.lng;

        console.log(lattitudeb);
        console.log(lngb);
    }).catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });

    axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json', {
        params: {
            units: 'imperial',
            origins: lattitude + ',' + lng, // here i get always 0 instead 
                                               of the new updated value
            destinations: lattitudeb + ',' + lngb,
            key: 'AIzaSyBpHirfserfserfser434efddf3ISMCDbgX33xAUB_Cwwi8'
        }
    }).then(function (r) {
        console.log(r);
    }).catch(function (e) {
        console.log(e);
    });

}
```

Comment: You should include all your requests in a single `promise` chain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those three requests:

```
    axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
```

```
    axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json', {
```

```
    axios.get('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json', {
```

are being sent pretty much simultaneously. The third one goes out before the first one receives latitude and other things. The value of `lattitude` is, at that point, still zero.

That's why you should: send the first one, `.then` send the one depending on its output. And good practice would be to pass required data as the first promise's return value, instead of using an outside variable.

Actually, here, #3 relies on the results of #1 and #2, and #1 and #2 are independent, am I reading it right? Therefore, the correct pattern would be

```
Promise.all([
//... first request here
//... second request here
])
.then(
//... third request here
```

Comment: Thanks, got it now